# Does it make sense to translate text before vectorization?

Tags: nlp

I and new to NLP and I want to ask this question from knowledgeable people.

I work on a Russian text document and I want to vectorize it using some pre-trained embeddings. There are much more pre-trained models in English compared to Russian. So I asked myself, I will lemmatize and tokenize my document so it should be pretty easy to translate it from Russian to English. Maybe instead of using Russian-trained embeddings, I will translate it and then use English embeddings?

Does it even make sense?

Comment: Was the answer helpful? If so, consider marking it as correct.

Comment: @noe Unofrtunately no, it wasn't very helpful. I am aware of RuBERT and my question was concerned specifically about translating text before computing vector representations. Only one line from your answer was relevant for that question, namely the first one: "This largely depends on the specific task you will be using the text for.". I guess this is true, but I was hoping for a more detailed answer like in which cases it might work and in which it doesn't. "this depends" doesn't help very much with my problem. But thank you for your time and attention for my problem!

Comment: Ok, I'd better delete the answer so your question gets more attention.